# Place Holder should be visible until type in textbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a simple question regarding usability...

Currently am working Mobile Application using HTML5 and PhoneGap.
Here I need to show the placeholder until user type something in that text-box. Placeholder should be visible if he didn't type anything but focus on that Text-box. This is because users typically press the tab before reading the next field in which case the empty text is already gone and the user has harder time knowing what to type. like [Twitter Login Page](https://twitter.com/) Can we do same in my application using HTML5 features?

**Its works fine (not hide when Focus)in Browsers... but not in Mobile**

Is there any solution for this??...

[image]

Comment: So what's wrong with using the usual `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: Placeholder attributes erases on focus

Comment: If you navigate a form using tab key, users typically press the tab before reading the next field in which case the empty text is already gone and the user has harder time knowing what to type.

Comment: I need shows the Placehoder until user type something in textbox ! Its shouldnot hide when focus in that TextBox

Comment: @tymeJV Can't speak for mobile, but a quick test in FF and Chrome leaves the placeholder in place until I actually type something.

Comment: @Sirko its OK in Browsers. but not in Mobile Device ! :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will preserve the text until the user starts typing:

Demo:     http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/JERQf/2/

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="Im a placeholder!"/>

var placeholder = $("#test").val();

$("#test").keydown(function() {
    if (this.value == placeholder) {
        this.value = '';
    }
}).blur(function() {
    if (this.value == '') {
        this.value = placeholder;
    }
});
```

I also added a `blur()` function, if the user enters nothing, then it fills the field with the placeholder again.

Comment: @tymeJV Can I make one suggestion? [Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/JERQf/3/). I added a keyup event so that if you type something and then backspace it away competely, the placeholder reappears in the box without having to blur.

Comment: Its not hide when test in Mobile !

Comment: Now am testing with ADT(Android Development Kit) Here we have its Virtal Device.. in this its not hide !\

Comment: With the Android SDK you can specify OS version and more, what specs are you testing on? Latest and greatest with 4.x, or something more common like 2.3.x?

Comment: @tymeJV Now using your code its working fine. But there is a problem. when we click on the textbox first charecter is append after the "placeholder" text. But in actually i need to workout from beginning of the text box.. what i can do ?

Comment: You mean the caret position is at the end of the text? Not too sure what you can do about that..sorry :\

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good cross-browser solution utilizing Modernizr for fallback

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search text" />
```

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="modernizr.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){

    $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
      var input = $(this);
      if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.val('');
        input.removeClass('placeholder');
      }
    }).blur(function() {
      var input = $(this);
      if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.addClass('placeholder');
        input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
      }
    }).blur();
    $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
      $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
          input.val('');
        }
      })
    });

}

</script>
```

Comment: where's the link to modernizer?